# Cannot add certain tag to question

Tags: support, tags

I edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668765/upload-data-to-server-and-record-audio) yesterday, and added the tag [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap).

However, I happened to come upon the same question today and noticed that this tag is missing. I tried to edit the post to add the tag but received the message

> Nothing appears to have changed.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Same problem, but not a dupe because of the specificity.

Comment: @LanceRoberts so for every tag we should post new Meta question?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The title of mine is more general, but obviously not the content. It makes more sense as an FAQ type post, but maybe it doesn't qualify on frequency?

Comment: @shadow wizard, No, we need a canonical question to link to as a dupe.  This one has a good title for that, so maybe it would work.

Comment: @Lance good chance there is such question already, got to go now but will look later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap) tag is a synonym of the [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova) tag, which is already present on the post*.

Arguably the message could be a bit more direct in identifying this, but I imagine it's not a terribly common problem.

<sub>*I *thought* that the tag selector inserted the synonym for you in these cases, which would have been a more obvious noop, but I'm pretty sure now that I completely imagined that.</sub>